# Using a select statement as criteria for an update query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to put together a query that updates a field within a table. I'm attempting to run a sub select query that gives me a number, and then use that number that resulted from the sub-query as part of the criteria for the update query.

```
USE EMMS
Update  [2_import_VZW_tbl_SMTN]
    set [2_import_VZW_tbl_SMTN].[Client_ID] =[tbl_Foundation_Account].[Client_ID] 
where ([tbl_Foundation_Account].[Foundation_Account_ID] =
           (Select TOP 1  tbl_Foundation_Account.Foundation_Account_ID
            FROM tbl_Foundation_Account 
                INNER JOIN [2_Import_tbl_AWCDSU]
                  ON tbl_Foundation_Account.Foundation_Account_ID =
                    [2_Import_tbl_AWCDSU].[ECPD Profile ID]))
```

My issue is I keep receiving this error

> The multi-part identifier
>   tbl_Foundation_Account.Foundation_Account_ID" could not be bound.

Am I using the sub-query incorrectly? When I've received this error before, it's been because of some ambiguity in the table or field names, but this time I've checked for all that and it should be fine. Can anyone explain what SQL sin I have committed?

Comment: The tbl_Foundation_Account columns are not available outside the sub-query.

Comment: how would you join all these three tables in a select query at the moment your update statement has three tables but you have only defined relation between two tables how the table `2_import_VZW_tbl_SMTN` is related to any of the other two tables `2_Import_tbl_AWCDSU` or `tbl_Foundation_Account`.

Comment: You have a table name starting with a number, AND a column name with spaces ? What is this... thing ?

Comment: @cosmo0 The spacing in the column name is how the raw data file uploads into the table. The table is an import table that is used for cleanup before it hits the final table. The final table does not include spacing lol. As for the number at the beginning of the table name, that's on me, but that's a whole other story haha.

Answer (score 1):

On the error

> The multi-part identifier
>   tbl_Foundation_Account.Foundation_Account_ID" could not be bound.

This is because the table column  `[tbl_Foundation_Account].[Client_ID]` does not exists in the scope of outer `UPDATE`query .
The only table the outer query has an inkling about is `[2_import_VZW_tbl_SMTN]` and it does not have a column like  `[tbl_Foundation_Account].[Client_ID]`.
It is akin to writing a column name with a typo or like you said

> When I've received this error before, it's been because of some
>   ambiguity in the table or field names

Please try a query like below.
Note that I am using Inner query syntax and ensuring that a single value is returned by using

```
    select top 1 [Client_ID]
```

in the inner query. rest of the query syntax is same.

```
USE EMMS

Update  [2_import_VZW_tbl_SMTN]
set [2_import_VZW_tbl_SMTN].[Client_ID] =
                    (   
                        select top 1 [Client_ID]  
                            from [tbl_Foundation_Account] 
                        where [Foundation_Account_ID] =
                           (
                           Select TOP 1  a.Foundation_Account_ID
                                FROM tbl_Foundation_Account a
                            INNER JOIN [2_Import_tbl_AWCDSU] b
                                  ON a.Foundation_Account_ID = b.[ECPD Profile ID]
                           )
                    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Another poster submitted this answer earlier, but then deleted it. I was able to try it before they deleted it and it works exactly how I needed it to work. I will use this as the right answer unless someone else can tell me why this is a bad Idea.

```
    USE EMMS
Update  [2_import_VZW_tbl_SMTN]
    set [2_import_VZW_tbl_SMTN].[Client_ID] = [tbl_Foundation_Account].[Client_ID] 
from [tbl_Foundation_Account]
where ([tbl_Foundation_Account].[Foundation_Account_ID] =
           (Select TOP 1  tbl_Foundation_Account.Foundation_Account_ID
            FROM tbl_Foundation_Account 
            INNER JOIN [2_Import_tbl_AWCDSU]
            ON tbl_Foundation_Account.Foundation_Account_ID = [2_Import_tbl_AWCDSU].[ECPD Profile ID]))
```

Comment: This was the answer given by @dasblinkenlight